# change dtype with pynco in Netcdf

Tags: numpy, python-xarray, cdo-climate, nco, pynco

I was wondering how to change the dtype from float32 to float64 of coordinates.

I can run the following code in the terminal

```
ncap2 -s 'lat=double(lat); lon=double(lon)' infile.nc outfile.nc
```

However when I try the following `ncap2` command in python I get the error  *too many input files*.

```
nco.ncap2(input='infile.nc', output='outfile.nc', options=['-s','lat=double(lat); lon=double(lon);'])
```

also tried with `ncatted2`

```
nco.ncatted(input='infile.nc', output='out.nc', options=['-a','lat=double(lat);  lon=double(lon);'])
```

This one just compiles without doing anything.

Comment: Is the "doubel" just a typo here or was it also an error in your script?

Comment: Oh that was just a typo. Have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it is the spaces in the options string messing it up, the `cdo` and `nco` bindings don't like padding spaces when there is more than one option (i.e. it would be like trying your direct terminal command without the surrounding quote marks on the `-s` option).

This should work, it did for me:

```
nco.ncap2(input='infile.nc', output='outfile.nc', options=['-s','lat=double(lat);lon=double(lon)'])
```